# Setting module name to be different from directory name in SwiftPM

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift library with a core module plus optional bonus modules. I would like to use the following directory layout, mapping to exported Swift package names as shown:

```
Taco/
  Source/
    Core/        → import Taco
    Toppings/    → import TacoToppings
    SideDishes/  → import TacoSideDishes
```

To my eyes, that’s a sensible-looking project layout. However, if I’m reading the docs right, this will pollute the global module namespace with unhelpful names like “Core”. It seems that SwiftPM will only export a module whose name is identical to the directory name, and thus I have to do this:

```
Taco/
  Source/
    Taco/
    TacoToppings/
    TacoSideDishes/
```

Is there a way to configure `Package.swift` to use the tidier directory layout above and still export the desired module names?

Alternatively, is it possible to make the Core, Toppings, and SideDishes modules internal to the project, and export them all to the world as one big Taco module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not currently a clean way to do this, but it seems like a reasonable request. I recommend filing an enhancement request at http://bugs.swift.org for it.

There is one "hacky" way you can do this:

Create your sources in the desired internal layout:

```
Sources/Core
Sources/Toppings
```

Add additional symbolic links for the desired module names:

```
ln -s Core Sources/Taco
ln -s Toppings Sources/TacoToppings
```

Add an `exclude` directive to the manifest to ignore the non-desired module name:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Taco",
    exclude: ["Sources/Core", "Sources/Toppings"]
)
```

> is it possible to make the Core, Toppings, and SideDishes modules internal to the project, and export them all to the world as one big Taco module?

No, unfortunately there is no way to do this currently, and it requires substantial compiler work to be able to support.

Comment: Thanks. I’d say the symlinks are worse than the longer directory names — but it’s always good to have options on the table!

Comment: The "hacky" method causes Xcode 14 to become **not responding**